# Handling large json responses - Android

Tags: android, json, gson

For a rest api call , I am getting a very large response and in some devices it is leading to OutOfMemory exception. Right now what I am doing is the response from http call is taken to a stringBuilder and then parsed to class using Gson.
Is this the right way to do it? Is there a better calling mechanism to avoid this memory error? How usually this kind of very large responses are handled in android? Is there any other methods other than the normal HTTP call

Please help

Comment: Did you check the Volley for this?

Comment: [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: You should also look into [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: If the response is that big it sounds like a badly implemented rest call. Add some pagination or reduce the data set returned.

Comment: Volley save all response in a byte array, so if your response is bigger than the memory heap size (16MB for most devices) it will crash with a OutOfMemory exception. You need a lib that allow you to parse your inputStream to Object directly like Jackson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recomend you to use Jackson lib  : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload

Jackson allow you to parse your inputStream or a file to Objects or Map directly, so you don't need to save your large JSON in a String or byte array to avoid memory error.